# FancyBox - iframe

Tags: button, iframe, fancybox

I would like to add a button in the footer of an iframe, but it can not be hidden if there is a scrollbar.

Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible. Did you try something already?

Comment: I would put the button on the bottom, increased the bottom ...
padding: [15,15,50,15]


$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".various").fancybox({
  maxWidth : 800,
  maxHeight : 600,
  fitToView : false,
  width  : '100%',
  height  : '100%',
  autoSize : true,
  closeClick : false,
  openEffect : 'elastic',
  closeEffect : 'elastic',
  padding     : [15,15,50,15],
  fitToView   : true

 });
});

Comment: In this example I used Bootstrap, bootstrap but is simpler

http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/395/imagemwt.png

Comment: Set the button in the `title` ... here is an example of adding social icons to the (fancybox) `title` http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/ ... you could use the same principle for your button (no need of messing with the padding)

Comment: ISTEPANIUK 
->thank you, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 500,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '100%',
    height      : '100%',
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';
            this.title += '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit">Cadastrar Produto</button>';
        }
    },


     helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    } 


});



</script>
</body>
```